# Получить данные из синхронного fetch

Tags: javascript

```
async function position() {
    const pos = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve);
    });
    return  {
        long: pos.coords.longitude,
        lat: pos.coords.latitude,
        accuracy: pos.coords.accuracy,
        altitude: pos.coords.altitude,
        heading: pos.coords.heading,
        speed: pos.coords.speed,
        timestamp: pos.timestamp
    }
```

Как вывести в консоль данные с этой асинхронной функции? Через простой console.log(position()); возращается Promise pending

Comment: `position().then(c => console.log(c))`

Answer (score 0):

Надо обернуть вывод в консоль тоже в асинхронщину, увы

```
(async function() {
    let position = await position();
    console.log(position);
})();
```

либо ловить через колбэк >_<

```
position().then(data => console.log(data));
```